# Pandas dataframe - How to synthetically add a unique timestamp for existing date column, which contains only date but no time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a simple dataframe with a string index.
The string represents time (e.g. 2018-01-01), and contains duplications.
Applying pd.to_datetime() takes me in the right direction, and well converts the index from a string type into datetime type.
However it does not solves the duplications problem.
I would ideally wish to synthetically add some unique timeStamp (%h:%m:%s) to each index cell.
Can you please guide me how to achieve that?

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index = ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-01'], 
                  columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'] ).fillna(0)
```

That yields the following dataframe:

```
            A  B  C
2018-01-01  0  0  0
2018-01-01  0  0  0
2018-01-01  0  0  0
```

I would like to convert it for something like that (unique datetime index):

```
                     A  B  C
2018-01-01 00:00:01  0  0  0
2018-01-01 00:00:02  0  0  0
2018-01-01 00:00:03  0  0  0
```

Thanks ahead,
Shahar

Comment: all datetimes are always same in index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all values of datetimes are unique use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `unit` and `origin` parameter by first value if index and add to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(np.arange(len(df)), 
                                 unit='s', 
                                 origin=df.index[0]))
print (df)
                     A  B  C
2018-01-01 00:00:00  0  0  0
2018-01-01 00:00:01  0  0  0
2018-01-01 00:00:02  0  0  0
```

If there are multiple unique `datetime`s in index add timedeltas created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to `Datetimeindex`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index = ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-01',
                           '2018-02-01', '2018-02-01'], 
                  columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'] ).fillna(0)


df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index) + 
                  pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='s'))
print (df)
                     A  B  C
2018-01-01 00:00:00  0  0  0
2018-01-01 00:00:01  0  0  0
2018-01-01 00:00:02  0  0  0
2018-02-01 00:00:00  0  0  0
2018-02-01 00:00:01  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, that's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) in combination with [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to get the desired results.

Use:

```
df.index = (
    pd.to_datetime(df.index) + 
    pd.to_timedelta(range(1, len(df) + 1), unit='s'))

print(df)
```

This prints the resulting dataframe as:

```
                     A  B  C
2018-01-01 00:00:01  0  0  0
2018-01-01 00:00:02  0  0  0
2018-01-01 00:00:03  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, that's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

To express your task more generally (for multiple dates):

- you have a DataFrame with a *string* index, formatted like dates,
- you want to convert the index to *datetime*,
- but within each date set the time part to consecitive seconds.

To do it you can run:

```
df.index = pd.Series(pd.Timedelta('1S'), index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)).groupby(level=0)\
    .transform(lambda grp: grp.cumsum() + grp.index)
```

Steps:

- `pd.Series(pd.Timedelta('1S'), index=pd.to_datetime(df.index))` - create
  a *Series* filled with *one second* values and the index from *df*
  converted to *datetime*, for now still with no time part.
- `groupby(...)` - group it by dates.
- `transform(...)` - transform it with the lambda function given.
- `grp.cumsum()` - the time part alone - consecutive seconds.
- `+ grp.index` - add the date part.
- `df.index` - set the index in *df* to this result.

The result, for 2 dates, even when dates are "intermixed", is still OK:

```
            A  B  C
2018-01-01  0  0  0
2018-01-01  0  0  0
2018-01-01  0  0  0
2018-01-02  0  0  0
2018-01-02  0  0  0
2018-01-02  0  0  0
2018-01-01  0  0  0
```

If you have a DataFrame with a **single** date, you can still use this code
(you will have a single group only).